# Somebody help me find this Japanese font? I already have an idea for what it is

Tags: fonts, typography, japanese

So I have a font similar to this installed on my phone, called "cherrybomb" that I got from this website (I'll post the link below) but the thing about that font and the one in the picture is that the one I have doesn't include any kanji, which the font below does. I need help finding the version of the font with kanji, since without kanji it's basically unusable for me. I've searched various things on google like チェリーボムフォント　漢字 (Cherrybomb font Kanji) and I haven't found anything. Here is the website I originally got the font from: http://www.asterism-m.com/font/cherrybomb/

I doubt anyone will be able to find the kanji version of this font but on the off chance that you do thank you so much!

[image: cherrybomb font]

Comment: Since the font isn't available from the creator with 漢字, I think it'll be difficult to obtain a version with 漢字... I think it's unlikely that a full font exists. Maybe someone bought the font for commercial use and added some glyphs, like 正. The change log reads "added hiragana" in September 2012.

Comment: The screencap is from a youtube video so I doubt they bought the font (it's not like youtubers are rolling in that much money), but even though it would be strange it's possible. Thanks for your input. :)

Comment: That's one reason you should put as much context as possible into your original question. I thought it was a font from an app in your phone.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The red kanji comes from a free font [にくまるゴシック](http://www.fontna.com/freefont/1651/), one of [M+](http://mplus-fonts.osdn.jp/)-derivative fonts. All remaining kana letters are set in Cherry Bomb, as you said. The image above was created with Photoshop changing fonts without any adjustments.

Your image source seems to be [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/OJhm2ADRORw), in which they also use [Rounded M+](http://jikasei.me/font/rounded-mplus/) and [Hiragino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragino) (Mac built-in).